# Javascript: Object.create(null) For Arrays (Array.create(null) Equivalent)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype, proto

It is easy to initialize an object with a blank prototype: `Object.create(null)`. But, arrays don't have a convenient `Array.create` method like Objects do. So, what would be the array equivalent of `Object.create`?

What would be the best way to initialize a blank array regarding the accessing speed* of the resulting array? Or, would the accessing speed* in said blank array be slower than the accessing speed* a regularly `[]` initialized array?

Any and all constructive responses are greatly appreciated.

*What is meant by 'accessing speed' is how fast properties can be read from, and written to, the array.

Comment: In JS arrays are objects but special type of objects. Their `length` property distinguishes them from the normal objects which gets refreshed even if you do like `a = []; a[10] = "whatever";`. So array instantiation is best done by literally as `[]` or by calling the `Array` function as a factory or constructor.

Comment: Arrays are crucial to JS, and JavaScript engines are tailored to provide performance boosts where possible. If you start customising, walking around the ways Arrays are working, you'll get worse performance for sure.

Comment: As said, don't fiddle with basic objects and arrays. {} and [] are perfectly acceptable, totally readable, highly optimized, etc. Oh lord please don't write code where I'd have to test the functions that create an empty object or array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in creating an array with a blank (or any other customised) prototype. The use case for `Object.create(null)` is a map<sup>1</sup> where no prototype interferes with properties, but we don't have that problem with arrays and their integer indices.
If you insisted to do so,

```
Object.setPrototypeOf([], null)
```

will achieve this but create a very weird object that will break a lot of code that expects arrays to have certain methods.

> Or, would the property access speed in said blank array be slower than that of a regularly initialized array?

Yes, quite likely - *weird* objects always have a good chance of not being optimised as well as standard objects. In any case, it won't be faster.

<sub>1: Of course, they're deprecated in favour of [true `Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) now.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your constructive response. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I created A JS perf: https://jsperf.com/different-ways-of-creating-arrays/1 Your amazing way seems to be noticably faster than `new Array`, which is apparently even faster than the classical `[]`.

Comment: I don't think that's "noticeable". Also the initialisation snippet is broken. And  [never trust microbenchmarks](http://mrale.ph/talks/goto2015/#/71).

Comment: The initialisation snippet wont work in IE, Safari, or Opera because I am too lazy to make it universally compatible just for a benchmark. Try using chrome, then it will work.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct that that normally, it would optimize it out. That is why I use `void`: to tell the browser not to op out the code.

Comment: Why do you think `void` would disable optimisation?

Answer (score 1):

There would be no reason not to just use `[]` for creating an array. You can technically call `new Array()`, but it's literally the same as `[]`.

Under the hood, an `Array` really is just an `Object` with numbers as keys and some special logic to ensure key order (which `Object` technically doesn't have, though `Object` generally does maintain it's key order, this isn't a guarantee).

While you could technically use `Object.create(null)` to create your own implementation of Array, it will be far inferior in performance to the built-in Array since most engines will have special code to improve its performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your constructive response, however I am seeking for if an Array could be created without a prototype so that the browser don't have to do the extra check to see if the index you are accessing is a non-numerical method like `indexOf`.

Comment: @3.1415926535897932384626433833 That little check is so minuscule as to have virtually no performance impact (talking in the range of single-digit nanoseconds), even on huge data sets that would generally be unsuitable for using in an interpreted language without direct memory control. Using anything for an array other than the built-in `Array` will always be vastly inferior. It'd be the same as implementing your own `Number` class instead of using the built-in.

Comment: I thought so too until I created and looked at this jsPerf: https://jsperf.com/different-ways-of-creating-arrays/1

Comment: When I ran them, the first three came back literally identical. with the second 2 being the lowest. Even if it was faster creating, your read/write speeds are going to be far slower, and that's before you actually do anything with them. Not to mention the extra burden of just understanding the goofiness.